# What chromedriver supports Chrome browser version 81.0.4044.122?

Tags: python, macos, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I currently have chrome driver version 81.0.4044.69 which I figured should be working but it's still throwing the error saying "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81"??

Comment: Check this [link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=81.0.4044.69/) for a file called `notes.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Each version of ChromeDriver supports Chrome with matching major, minor and build version numbers. For example, ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.122 supports all Chrome versions that start with 81.0.4044.

Thus, Chromedriver 81.0.4044.69 supports chrome browser version 81.0.4044.122. You can download it from here, https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=81.0.4044.69/

Comment: It should, but with me I take Chromedriver 81.0.4044.69 and my Chrome is on version 81.0.4044.129 but I still get the error "SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81". Everywhere I see the incompatability is the problem but it is not the case with me. It should be compatible